# how to sum with groupby and withhas in lararvel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have 2 tables

1. invoice (id, service_inv_cat_id, etc..)
2. payment (id, invoice_id, amount)

I need to get the sum of amount in payment with groupby (service_inv_cat_id)

here is my code

```
$income_details_cat = Invoice::select('id', 'service_inv_cat_id')
        ->with(['service_inv_cat' => function ($q) {
            $q->select('id', 'name');}])   
        ->with(['payment' => function ($q) use ($year, $month){
            $q->select('id','invoice_id', 'amount')
            ->whereYear('paid_date', $year)
            ->whereMonth('paid_date', $month)
        ;}])
        ->whereHas('payment', function ($q) use ($year,$month) {
            return $q->where('type', 3)
            ->whereYear('paid_date', $year)
            ->whereMonth('paid_date', $month)
        ;})
        ->withSum(['payment' => function ($query) use ($year, $month){
            $query->whereYear('paid_date', $year)
            ->whereMonth('paid_date', $month);
        }], 'amount')
        ->get();
```

it returns the following
[image]

but I need to get the total sum of wallet,

I have tried added ->groupBy('service_inv_cat_id')

but it returns the following [image]

it returns the sum of payment of only one record, ex wallet has higher than 200 in total with many invoices as you can see in pic 1 but its returns only one

Comment: @Zia thank you for answer, but i have tried (with) or I could not understand your answer?

Comment: sorry i meant use join here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume service_cat and payment belongTo payment ?

```
$income_details_cat = Invoice::select('invoices.id', 'invoices.service_inv_cat_id', 'payments.amount')
->join('payments', 'invoices.id', '=', 'payments.invoice_id')
->with('service_inv_cat:id,name')
->sum('payments.amount')
->where('payments.type', 3)
->whereYear('payments.paid_date', $year)
->whereMonth('payments.paid_date', $month)
->groupBy('service_inv_cat_id')
->get();
```

I am a bit lost to be honest but I would re-write your code like this not sure why you have so many withs for the same thing I think you would get the same result as you have now if written like this:

```
$income_details_cat = Invoice::select('id', 'service_inv_cat_id')
->with('service_inv_cat:id,name', 'payment:id,invoice_id,amount')
->wherHas(['payment' => fn ($q) =>
        $q->where('type', 3)
        ->whereYear('paid_date', $year)
        ->whereMonth('paid_date', $month)
])
->get();
```

if you can show your relationships a bit clearer and explain what laser is ? I take it wallet is the sum of all amounts grouped by service_inv_cat_id

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, it worked with me but i had to delete ->sum('payments.amount') and add in select DB::raw('sum(payments.amount) as sums')